# Could not connect to any of ['/tmp/pyosqsockndnbir6z'] in osquery-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, operating-system, osquery

`Could not connect to any of ['/tmp/pyosqsockndnbir6z']`
Encountering this error in sentry repeatedly .
Also it is raised after below subprocess command. I haven't executed the below command in my code.
`/usr/bin/osqueryd --extensions_socket /tmp/pyosqsockndnbir6z --disable_database --disable_watchdog --disable_logging --ephemeral --config_path /dev/null`

[Error Image attached here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRWh4.png)

Please let me know what are possible reasons and solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very unclear to me.

When started, osquery should listen on that socket. There may be startup delays.

But I don't know your python code, and you have provided no information about what it's doing.